# Express-Validator With Express-Messages

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

Hey guys I want to make an messaging system for my upload webpage.

I use express-validator and connect-flash, express-messages

**app.js**

```
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');
.
.
.
app.post('/metin/ekle', [
  // username must be an email
  check('baslik', 'Baslik Gereklidir').notEmpty(),
  // password must be at least 5 chars long
  check('konu','Konu gereklidir').notEmpty(),
],function(req, res){

  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return req.flash('danger', {errors});//I dont know what do do exactly here
  }

    var metin = new Metin({
      baslik: req.body.baslik,
      yazar: req.body.yazar,
      konu: req.body.konu,
    });

        metin.save(function(err){
          if(err){
            console.log(err);
            return;
          } else {
            req.flash('success', 'Metin Eklendi');
            res.redirect("/metin/"+ metin._id);
          }
        });
      });
```

**And this is my article.pug:**

```
!= messages('my_message_template', locals)
    if errors
        each error, i in errors
          div(class="alert alert-danger") #{error.msg}
```

I dont know what to do exaclty where I decleared validationResult errs. I wrote msg but I know it is wrong. What can I or change my codes in order to message danger when I get express-validation errors?

Comment: It shows validation errors just like this:{"errors":[{"value":"","msg":"Baslik Gereklidir","param":"baslik","location":"body"},{"value":"","msg":"Konu gereklidir","param":"konu","location":"body"}]}  with pure express-validator

Comment: But I want to make errors in a danger box with express-messages.